# Create HTML table from array (loop specific)

Tags: javascript, loops, dom

Why does this loop not produce a table with 7 rows? I have tried with a regular for loop, while, forEach. I'm missing something.

```
  const MOUNTAINS = [
    {name: "Kilimanjaro", height: 5895, place: "Tanzania"},
    {name: "Everest", height: 8848, place: "Nepal"},
    {name: "Mount Fuji", height: 3776, place: "Japan"},
    {name: "Vaalserberg", height: 323, place: "Netherlands"},
    {name: "Denali", height: 6168, place: "United States"},
    {name: "Popocatepetl", height: 5465, place: "Mexico"},
    {name: "Mont Blanc", height: 4808, place: "Italy/France"}
  ];


let makeTable = (arr) => {
  let table = document.createElement('table');
  let row = document.createElement('tr');
  let data = document.createElement('td');
  for (let entry of arr) {
    table.appendChild(row).appendChild(data);
  }
  return table;
}

makeTable(MOUNTAINS)

//<table>
//  <tr>
//    <td></td>
//  </tr>
//</table>
```

Comment: You might need to do something like document.body.appendChild(table) before the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the elements must be unique, try this:

```
let makeTable = (arr) => {
  let table = document.createElement('table');
  for (let entry of arr) {
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    let data = document.createElement('td');
    table.appendChild(row).appendChild(data);
  }
  return table;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to append it to the `body` at the end. Also, you're not filling out the data to the columns, what you can do is iterate over the entries, create a column `data` for each attribute and append it to the `row` which will be added to the `table` each time:

```js
 const MOUNTAINS = [
    {name: "Kilimanjaro", height: 5895, place: "Tanzania"},
    {name: "Everest", height: 8848, place: "Nepal"},
    {name: "Mount Fuji", height: 3776, place: "Japan"},
    {name: "Vaalserberg", height: 323, place: "Netherlands"},
    {name: "Denali", height: 6168, place: "United States"},
    {name: "Popocatepetl", height: 5465, place: "Mexico"},
    {name: "Mont Blanc", height: 4808, place: "Italy/France"}
];


let makeTable = (arr) => {
  let table = document.createElement('table');
  for (let entry of arr) {
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    Object.values(entry).forEach(value => {
      let data = document.createElement('td');
      data.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
      row.appendChild(data);
    });
    table.appendChild(row);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(table);
  return table;
}

makeTable(MOUNTAINS)
```